# Accessing a dictionary within a list within a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

Take this dictionary for example:

```
{
 "Buildings": {
  "Building": [
  {
    "ID": "1000201",
    "Name": "HARTWIG MARIE DOROTHY ADMINISTRATION BUILDING",
    "Abbreviation": "HARTW",
    "Campus": "Stephen M Ross Athletic Campus"
  },
  {
    "ID": "1000700",
    "Name": "CRISLER CENTER",
    "Abbreviation": "CRIS",
    "Campus": "Stephen M Ross Athletic Campus"
  },
```

The list of dictionaries containing ID, Name, etc. continues.
I'm trying to access these inner dictionaries with a for loop.
campus_cds is a list of 16 numbers that the function get_buildings() takes in order to give the information above.

```
    for campus_cd in campus_cds:
       buildings = get_buildings(campus_cd)
       building = buildings['Buildings']
       bldg = building['Building']
```

So, I am able to get into the second dictionary with the line of code that is "building = buildings['Buildings']"

```
"Building": [
  {
    "ID": "1000201",
    "Name": "HARTWIG MARIE DOROTHY ADMINISTRATION BUILDING",
    "Abbreviation": "HARTW",
    "Campus": "Stephen M Ross Athletic Campus"
  },
```

But, when I try to do "bldg = building['Building']", I get the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__ getitem __'"

All I'm trying to do is access the value of the key 'Building', which is a list. Why doesn't this work?

After I'm able to access this list of dictionaries, I plan to loop through the list compare a given variable to 'Name' in each dictionary to find a match.

Comment: That means that `buildings['Buildings']` returned `None` and _not_ a list. Try `print building` to check it worked as expected.

Comment: It does. I get: {u'Building': [{u'Abbreviation': u'HARTW', u'Campus': u'Stephen M Ross Athletic Campus', u'ID': 1000201, u'Name': u'HARTWIG MARIE DOROTHY ADMINISTRATION BUILDING'}, and so on.

Comment: So the thing is, if I do "bldg = building['Building']" outside the for loop (resulting in the the buildings on the campus who has the last campus_cd in my list), the code works. Is it possible there there is just too much information?

Comment: Your for loop iterates over each item in `campus_cds`. Will they _all_ have valid data? The fact that your code works outside of the for loop implies that last item has valid data, but the previous items might not.

Comment: Wow. Savior. This was exactly it. I should have checked to see if they all contained data. Thank you so much!